# Open and close url in safari using objective-c program

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, safari, openurl

I have to open a URL in safari... and after doing some work on safari I have to close the safari...

my code is as below.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strPageUrl]];
```

Actually I have to share video on myspace.. if user has shared the video then I have to close safari and need to activate my application again.

I want to do something similar facebook SDK login with safari..

Please help me how to open this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

custom url schemes work only one way... Like if you opened safari from your application then you can't return back to your application unless the second application is also yours and you have implemented another custom url to return back to your application. Since safari was made by apple so it does not have info regarding your application.

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but you can try out `UIWebView` for requirement if it helps.

Comment: If you have ever used facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-v1.1-15-g397c0b6.zip here, they are using safari to login with facebook and after login safari get shut automatically and application get launch.

I want same.

Comment: I think it is not only with safari, login with facebook is done by safari only if the faceboook app is not installed, if so, facebook app will be in charge of re-directing to the application. I also need to do something similar to what facebook does in that case.